# Javascript parse JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Folks, DynamoDB call returns a JSON Object, which I would like to parse, and grab the password hash field

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(data)
console.log(jsonString)
```

output:

```
{"Count":1,"Items":[{"token":{"S":"token"},"uid":{"S":"33c02130-66b5-11e3-bdb0-7d9889f293b5"},"password":{"S":"$2a$10$ervzJ.DWjHOXRtJSugTaWuquI2OvPLyipa4YXecc/2KdQnmhrHxr6"},"username":{"S":"foo"},"plate":{"S":"dinner"},"name":{"S":"Test Name"},"server":{"S":"bar"}}]}
```

How would i parse this string, and retrieve the 'password' field?
The following code does not work:

```
console.log(jsonString.password)
console.log(jsonString.uid)
```

The following returns undefined:

```
console.log(data.password);
```

Thanks!

Comment: @PSL unfortunately that does not work, i get back 'undefined'

Comment: `data.Items[0].password`?

Comment: @Clive, closer!  { S: '$2a$10$ervzJ.DWjHOXRtJSugTaWuquI2OvPLyipa4YXecc/2KdQnmhrHxr6' }

Comment: `data.Items[0].password.S` then :)

Comment: If you don't stringify it, it would probably be much easier.

Comment: @Cmag, show us your ajax call. You don't need to `stringify(data)`. Your call, I suspect, has already taken the JSON string and converted it to an object, which is what you want. You can then do `data.Items[0].password.S` to get what you want.

Comment: Show us your ajax call, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already an object, so you can do this:

```
var str = {"Count":1,"Items":[{"token":{"S":"token"},"uid":{"S":"33c02130-66b5-11e3-bdb0-7d9889f293b5"},"password":{"S":"$2a$10$ervzJ.DWjHOXRtJSugTaWuquI2OvPLyipa4YXecc/2KdQnmhrHxr6"},"username":{"S":"foo"},"plate":{"S":"dinner"},"name":{"S":"Test Name"},"server":{"S":"bar"}}]};

alert(str.Items[0].password.S);
```

Comment: Not quite. While your example works, it misrepresents what actually is happening here. His `data`, like your `str` is not a string, but an object. His `data` object should not be `stringify`'d as he posted, but just used as it is. Like this: `data.Items[0].password.S`.